# Proper naming for a Time class

Tags: java, datetime

Which of these names is better: `time.getHours()` or `time.hours()`? And why?

```
public class Time implements Serializable {
    private final int hours;
    private final int minutes;

    public static Time from(Calendar calendar) {
        int hoursIn24HourFormat = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        return new Time(hoursIn24HourFormat, minutes);
    }

    public Time(int hours, int minutes) {
        this.hours = hours;
        this.minutes = minutes;
    }

    // or may be getHours() name is better?
    public int hours() {
        return hours;
    }

    // or may be getMinutes() name is better?
    public int minutes() {
        return minutes;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Time)) {
            return false;
        }
        Time other = (Time) obj;
        return (hours == other.hours) &&
               (minutes == other.minutes);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return toMinutesOfDay();
    }

    private int toMinutesOfDay() {
        return hours * 60 + minutes;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return twoDigitString(hours) + ":" + twoDigitString(minutes);
    }

    private static String twoDigitString(int timeComponent) {
        return (timeComponent < 10)
                ? ("0" + timeComponent)
                : String.valueOf(timeComponent);
    }

    public boolean before(Time time) {
        return toMinutesOfDay() < time.toMinutesOfDay();
    }

    public boolean after(Time time) {
        return toMinutesOfDay() > time.toMinutesOfDay();
    }

    public boolean within(Time fromIncluded, Time toIncluded) {
        return (!fromIncluded.after(this)) && (!this.after(toIncluded));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd name the class `TimeOfDay` to be absolutely clear about its purpose.

Consider adding validation to the constructor (0 ≤ hour ≤ 23 and 0 ≤ minutes ≤ 59).

Because `before()` and `after()` are [predicates](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39399/naming-of-predicate-methods), I'd rename them to `isBefore(TimeOfDay t)` and `isAfter(TimeOfDay t)`.

I prefer `getHours()` over `hours()`.

If you prefer `hours()`, you *might* consider just exposing `public final int hours, minutes;` instead.  Normally, you want to reserve the flexibility to change the internal representation of your object (for example, to store just `minutesOfDay` instead of `hours` and `minutes`).  However, since those fields are `final`, and you're more or less committed to the representation due to serialization, there's not much to be gained by wrapping the value in a method, other than consistency with tradition, and you would already violate tradition slightly anyway by choosing `hours()` over `getHours()`.

Answer (score 4):

It is a matter of taste, so there is no 'better'. But more common seams to be `time.getHours();` because often the conventions of [JavaBean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans#JavaBean_conventions) are used.

If you work in a team, I would discuss the naming conventions to use with them.

Comment: Coming from a fair amount of time spent with Java and Android, I would second this. You usually only see something like `time.hours` if `hours` is a public member.